Changing size of Gauge element
I created a circular gauge for progressive view with stop button in middle of it, but the circle looks quite big. I am unable to reduce it's size. How do I change the size of circle?
Code:
import SwiftUI

struct DownloadProgressGauge: View {
    var body: some View {
        Gauge(value: 100, in: 0...200) {
            Image(systemName: "gauge.medium").resizable().frame(width: 30, height: 30.0)
        } currentValueLabel: {
            Image(systemName: "stop.fill").font(.caption).bold()
                .foregroundStyle(Color.systemBlue)
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.33)
        }
        .gaugeStyle(.accessoryCircularCapacity)
        .tint(Color.systemBlue)
        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
    }
} 

This is how big circle looks after running the code:

I am looking for something like this i.e. gauge in smaller size:


You can make almost anything smaller with scaleEffect. Combine that with a larger image for the stop button, and you get something similar to the proportions you want:
Gauge(value: 100, in: 0...200) {
    
} currentValueLabel: {
    Image(systemName: "stop.fill").resizable().bold().frame(width: 18, height: 18)
        .foregroundStyle(Color.blue)
}
.gaugeStyle(.accessoryCircularCapacity)
.tint(Color.blue)
.scaleEffect(0.5)



That said, I don't recommend using a built-in GaugeStyle if you have a very specific design in mind. You can create your own GaugeStyle.
struct VariableSizeCircularStyle: GaugeStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .stroke(.primary.opacity(0.5), lineWidth: 4)
            Circle()
                .trim(to: configuration.value)
                .stroke(.primary, style: .init(lineWidth: 4, lineCap: .round))
                .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
            configuration.currentValueLabel
        }
    }
}

extension GaugeStyle where Self == VariableSizeCircularStyle {
    static var variableSizeCircular: VariableSizeCircularStyle { .init() }
}

// Usage:

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Gauge(value: 100, in: 0...200) {
            
        } currentValueLabel: {
            Image(systemName: "stop.fill").resizable().bold().frame(width: 12, height: 12)
        }
        .gaugeStyle(.variableSizeCircular)
        .foregroundStyle(Color.blue)
        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
    }
}


Thanks @Sweeper for sharing GaugeStyle! Before you posted the answer, I tried with scale effect and it worked, but now I switched to gauge style to have more control over it in future. I will have one issue with it where initially the circle is solid blue before the download starts and then it turns to blue with less opacity and then solid blue progresses on it as download continues. It could probably due to the values I have in "Gauge(value: 100, in: 0...200)". I will try out a few things and will post it another question if needed.
